# How to make bootstrap 3 dropdown menu working for no JS user

Tags: css

I'm looking how to convert dropdown menu on bootstrap for no JS user.

I already see its possible in full CSS but I'm not very friendly with CSS ...

Any one can help me ?

Comment: Do you want tutorial?

Comment: Tutorail, code no matter. I just want help on how to convert bootstrap3 dropdown menu for no JS user

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a possibility.

Download this [Bootstrap](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css)

Implement this code <kbd>[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rD4nf/)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="brand">Project name</a>
        <div class="nav-collapse">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">2-level Dropdown <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form action="" class="navbar-search pull-left">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search-query span2">
          </form>
          <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="#" href="#">Menu</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Regular link</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1">
    <li>
        <a href="#">2-level Menu <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">Menu</a>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">Menu</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav {
    padding: 9px 0;
}

.dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.nav-tabs .dropdown-menu, .nav-pills .dropdown-menu, .navbar .dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.navbar .sub-menu:before {
    border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-top: 7px solid transparent;
    left: -7px;
    top: 10px;
}
.navbar .sub-menu:after {
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 6px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    left: 10px;
    top: 11px;
    left: -6px;
 }
```

Comment: this needs JavaScript from bootstrap.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case of someone wants a short answer.

**HTML**

```
 <li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

You can try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rD4nf/22/)

Comment: your fiddle needs JavaScript. demonstrate it somewhere without JavaScript.

Answer (score -5):

In your css put:

```
.dropdown-menu {display:block;}

.open > .dropdown-menu {display:block !important;}
```

And your javascript:

```
$(".dropdown-menu").hide();
```

Comment: He asks for solution without js, and you giving him answer with js. Well done